# can't setState, always null

Tags: php, session, yii

can't seem to setState. What are some possibilities that it might not be able to? I tried changing the names. Anything else I should look into? I am retrieving this in my product model aftersave. The state always show up as null.

```
if(Yii::app()->user->hasState('addImages' )) 
    $userImages = Yii::app()->user->getState('addImages');
else 
    $userImages = array();

$userImages[] = array(
     "path"=>$save_path.$rename,
     "thumb" => $save_th.$rename,
     "filename" => $rename,
);
Yii::app()->user->setState('addImages', $userImages);
```

then in the product model

```
if(Yii::app()->user->hasState('addImages')){//<--always null
    $images = Yii::app()->user->getState('addImages'); 
//do something
```

Comment: Are you sure `afterSave` is being called?

Comment: Yes, it is saving my other aftersave models but those are not using setstate.

Comment: so i just tried the other way `Yii::app()->session['addImages']`, it is the same, null.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand me. The code above looks fine so one of the possible options is the call to `afterSave()` for this specific class is not happening. You can add code to set a db flag or add a log to confirm this.